# Skipping an unknown number of words in python

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

So I usually am just extracting phrases and print them out in a pre specified format after I run a script over a document.

I use this code to split up my setences

```
def iterphrases(text):
    return re.split(r'\.\s', re.sub(r'\.\s*$', '', text))
```

Then I read the file and if the word is in the file I append the sentence into a dictionary.

```
def find_keywords(OutputFile, keys):
    phrase_combos= keys + [x.upper() for x in keys] + [x.lower() for x in keys] + [x.capitalize() for x in keys] 
   keys = list(set(phrase_combos))
    cwd = os.getcwd()
print 'Working in current directory : ', cwd
cwdfiles = os.listdir(cwd)

    filenames = []
    for item in cwdfiles:
        if item[-4:] == '.txt':
        filenames.append(item)

    out = defaultdict(list) 
    for filename in filenames:
        for phrase in iterphrases(open(filename).read()):
             for keyword in keys:

                if phrase.lower().index('no') < phrase.index(keyword): 
                    out[keyword].append((filename, phrase))
    my_dict= dict(**out)
```

I do some stuff with this and it has worked great for a while but now I need to find things that are NOT something. I could find many phrases but some skip words and would not match exactly for example if my phrase was the word foo.

No foo. Not foo. Not foo or bar. No foo and no bar. Are all in my dictionary but I also need:

```
Not bar or foo. Not bar or foo or banana. Not bar or banana or foo. Not bar, banana, or foo. Not bar, foo, or banana.
```

To all appear as a results as well. Right now it can not match on it because bar foo is not right next to a negating word. Is there a way I can say 'Match if negative words appear regardless of how many other words are between the word/phrase of interest as long as you are in the same sentence' ?

Creating something like this for example.

```
This is a group of Text. There is no foo. There is no bar. There is no foo 
or bar. There is no bar or foo. I have coffee. I have a bar. No bar for you.
```

Ought to return :
     {'bar' : There is no bar. , There is no bar or foo. , There is no foo or bar., No bar for you.}

Comment: ``try: if phrase.lowercase().index(' no ') < phrase.index(keyword): out[keyword].append((filename, phrase)); except ValueError: pass`` should match all cases where ' no ' is mentioned somewhere before your keyword and raise an exception whenever one of the two is not inside. edit: of course you want 'no' not 'not' - and you might have to do something for the whitespace around it or the 'not' variation.

Comment: Well, now it looks like your keyword is simply 'no bar' which you need to search inside the lowercase version of your sentence... otherwise you should also return ``There is no foo or bar`` in your output.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lowercase' . I guess phrase is not the same type of object? I would like to return There is no foo or bar. I just forgot. sorry! I'll edit it.

Comment: try ``lower()``, my bad. Also try removing the spaces around 'no'.

Comment: I get substring not found still as a value error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching with a regular expression. You can search a list of keywords and negate them with a list of negations.
The trick is to compile a regular expression which searches inside your sentences for 'a negation word in somewhere before my keyword'. This means:

```
re.compile(r'\b{!s}\b.+\b{!s}\b'.format(neg, keyword), re.I)
```

Where `\b` means 'word boundary'. So it is a word, followed by gibberish (`.+`) followed by a word. And with the `format` we set the words to the negation word and the keyword. `re.I` sets the ignore-cases-flag.

Now with all your examples and some examples I think you don't want to match like 'Nonono this is not the right foo' or 'Anonymus foo...' I came up with the following, which should give you a starting point:

```py
import re
text = 'Not foo. Not No foo. Not foo or bar. No foo and no bar. Not bar or foo. Not bar or foo or banana. Not bar or banana or foo. Not bar, banana, or foo. Not bar, foo, or banana. This is a group of Text. There is no foo. There is no bar. There is no foo or bar. There is no bar or foo. I have coffee. I have a bar. No bar for you. Nonono, this is the wrong foo. Nono this is also a wrong foo. Anonymous foo.'
keywords = ['foo']
negated = ['no', 'not']

phraselist = re.split(r'\.\s', text)

out = {}

for phrase in phraselist:
    for keyword in keywords:
        for neg in negated:
            regex = re.compile(r'\b{!s}\b.+\b{!s}\b'.format(neg, keyword), re.I)
            if regex.search(phrase.lower()):
                try:
                    if not phrase in out[keyword]:
                        out[keyword].append(phrase) 
                except KeyError:
                    out[keyword] = [phrase]

print(out)

expected = 'Not foo. Not No foo. Not foo or bar. No foo and no bar. Not bar or foo. Not bar or foo or banana. Not bar or banana or foo. Not bar, banana, or foo. Not bar, foo or banana. There is no foo. There is no foor or bar. There is no bar or foo.'
print(expected)
```

The output is:

```
{'foo': ['Not foo', 'Not No foo', 'Not foo or bar', 'No foo and no bar', 'Not ba
r or foo', 'Not bar or foo or banana', 'Not bar or banana or foo', 'Not bar, ban
ana, or foo', 'Not bar, foo, or banana', 'There is no foo', 'There is no foo or
bar', 'There is no bar or foo']}
Not foo. Not No foo. Not foo or bar. No foo and no bar. Not bar or foo. Not bar
or foo or banana. Not bar or banana or foo. Not bar, banana, or foo. Not bar, fo
o or banana. There is no foo. There is no foor or bar. There is no bar or foo.
```

Comment: It works and now that I review my regular expressions (I wanted to make sure I had no questions and understood the code) this makes sense! Thank you so much!